# toggleClass: How does this CSS work?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, ember.js

I am using the following animations (reimplemented with Ember JS), but failing to understanding how this CSS works.  Refer to the link below.

https://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/Atyop

```
#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}


#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

toggleClass('open') is triggered when the div is clicked, but what is `open` actually?  Is it a subclass of nav-icon?  And if it is possible with ember, would simply toggling between the two CSS blocks (open and not) show the animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toggleClass('open')` adds/removes the class 'open' to the div. When 'open' is added to the div, each span element inside of the div is changed in a different way through the pseudo `nth-child()` selector. The full CSS for `#nav-icon3` is here:

```
/* Icon 3 */

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(2),#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 36px;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

The transition is set on all span elements inside of the icons in the code below. You need `transition: .25s ease-in-out;` present in order for the animation to occur on all of the child span elements.

```
  #nav-icon1 span, #nav-icon3 span, #nav-icon4 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #d3531a;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Great and comprehensive answer

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the [Jquery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), this will simply toggle the css class specified in the parameter. That is, if the element(s) you call this method on have the class `open`, that class will be removed. If they do not have the class `open` they will be given that css class.